# Как настроить аутентификацию для веб-сервис по логину и паролю без использования домена

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wsdl

Здравствуйте, столкнулся со сложной проблемой и к сожалению вторую неделю не могу её разрешить. Помогите плиз

Что дано: Есть веб-сервис, написанный на C#, выполняющий интеграцию различных систем между собой. Развернут он естественно на IIS.

Что надо сделать: Реализовать аутентификацию по логину и паролю!

[Custom Authentication and Authorization in WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698862/Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-WCF)

Я добавил класс CustomUserNameValidator в нём есть метод Validate.

```
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{

    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (null == userName || null == password)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();                
        }

        if (!(userName == "1" && password == "1"))
        {
            throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
        }
    }
}
```

Создал конечную точку

```
<services>
  <service name="КОНТРАКТ" behaviorConfiguration="MyBeh">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSBinding" contract="КОНТРАКТ"/>
```

Создал привязку

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSBinding">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Добавил поведение

```
        <behavior name="MyBeh">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ПРОСТРАНСТВО_ИМЕН.CustomUserNameValidator,ИМЯ_СБОРКИ" />
        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
```

Собственно и все.

Первая проблема заключается в том, что Validate никогда не вызывается, хотя отладчик ловит что экземпляр CustomUserNameValidator создается.

И далее самое непонятное: Когда я пытаюсь работаю в VisualStudio мне доступен только IIS Express. Там есть только два типа аутентификации: Анонимная и Windows, Basic нет. При анонимной в браузере WSDL открывается, но он браузер у меня ничего не запрашивает, Validate тоже не срабатывает.

Если использую только Windows. То у меня происходит redirect на ~Account/Login.
И затем 404 ошибка, естественно.
Хотя сама аутентификация через AD проходит, так как мой компьютер включен в домен, он показывает что именно я выполнил вход... Validate тоже не срабатывает.

При отключенных обоих типах, браузер запрашивает логин и пароль, но к сожалению ничего не принимает, чтобы я ему не вводил.

Пытаюсь, тоже самое сделать через IIS 7 и там я переключал разные типы аутентификации.

Basic. Браузер у меня спрашивает логин и пароль. Ввожу 1 и 1. Он их не принимает. Ввожу учетку от AD. Тоже самое redirect на ~Account/Login.
И затем 404 ошибка, естественно.

Windows. Тоже аутентифицирется только по учетке AD.
Но при этом ругается на конфиг:

> Схемы аутентификации, настроенные на узле
>   ("IntegratedWindowsAuthentication"), не допускают использование схем,
>   основанных на привязке "WSHttpBinding" ("Anonymous"). Убедитесь, что
>   режим SecurityMode имеет значение Transport или
>   TransportCredentialOnly. Кроме того, эта проблема может быть разрешена
>   путем изменения схем аутентификации для этого приложения при помощи
>   средства управления IIS при помощи свойства
>   ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes в элементе
>    файла конфигурации приложения путем
>   обновления свойства привязки ClientCredentialType или путем настройки
>   свойства AuthenticationScheme элемента HttpTransportBindingElement.

Собственно мне не надо AD-аутентификаций, я хочу сделать обычную аутентификацию по логину и паролю. Я не понимаю, где я и что сделал не так. Помогите плиз...

Comment: так у вас в ошибке все что нужно сделать уже написано

Comment: В этом и проблема, я и сделал все в точь-в-точь, однако все равно кастомная аутентификация не срабатывает! Программа в нее не входит!

Comment: описание вопроса https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Приложенная мною ссылка реализует абсолютно тоже самое. Эта инструкция не сработает!

Comment: Значит вы изначально делаете, что-то не так. В MSDN весь код рабочий. Пример реализации https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513(v=vs.110).aspx